# Can I start this simple CSS transition without using javascript

Tags: javascript, css

This is a simple CSS transition.

```css
div.simple_transition {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  -webkit-transition: width 5s;
  /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
  transition: width 5s;
  &:hover {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Simple Transition</h1>
<p>NoJS Animation starts when hovering the element</p>
<div class="simple_transition"></div>
<p>
  <b>Note:</b> This example does not work in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions.</p>
```

So I want it to start the transition programmatically for example right after the browser loads the page without using the mouse hover css selector. I know that I can do this with javascript and I managed to do this with a simple  code.

```js
//Based on https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_transition1
$(document).ready(function() {
  var elm = $('div.simple_transition');
  elm.attr('class', 'should-be-likethis');
  console.log('working on it');
});
```

```css
div.simple_transition {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  -webkit-transition: width 5s;
  /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
  transition: width 5s;
  &:hover {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.should-be-likethis {
  -webkit-transition: width 5s;
  /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
  transition: width 5s;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<h1>Simple Transition</h1>

<p id='text'>With jQuery animation starts without hovering the element</p>
<div class="simple_transition"></div>
<p><b>Note:</b> This example does not work in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions.</p>
```

**Can I do this without using javascript only with CSS?**
In fact in my current project I am already using javascript (ajax) for handling some data-related queries and I am also using a sass compiler so I would prefer that to write everything that is related to the styles in a CSS.

Comment: use animation with forwards?

Comment: Maybe what you want is an animation instead of a transition, as @TemaniAfif suggested? You can also add a small delay to this animation if you feel like: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-delay

Comment: Thanks for the info about the delay, @ Andy Hoffman answer worked like a charm for me and @Temani Afif was right when he said "use animation with forwards" now I get what he was talking about :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I changed your class name to match the new behavior (animation, not a transition). We're animating from `100px` to the full width of the viewport.

```css
html, body { margin: 0; } /* Prevent scrollbar */

div.simple_animation {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  animation: 5s loading forwards;
}

@keyframes loading {
  to {
    width: 100vw;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="simple_animation"></div>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q5gm3fs4/2/)

Answer (score 0):

css

```
.js-loading *,
.js-loading *:before,
.js-loading *:after {
  animation-play-state: paused !important;
}
```

I have been out of web development a bit, but I think this works on most modern browsers